# unable to send stored password as an argument to comparepassword() method node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, passport.js, bcrypt

I have been struggling to get the password compared by sending already stored/hashed password in mongoose to called function to perform passoword comparison functionality.  Below is the code for **users.js**. i commented the problematic section. **For debugging purpose., I have printed the argument values in both the calling and called functions as shown at the end.**

**users.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var multer = require('multer');
var upload = multer({dest: './uploads'});
var passport = require('passport');
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;

var User=require('../models/user');
    router.post('/login',
      passport.authenticate('local',{failureRedirect:'/users/login',failureFlash:'Invalid username or password'}),
      function(req, res) {
        req.flash('success','You are now logged in!');
        res.redirect('/');
        console.login("Login Working!...");
      });

      passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
      done(null, user.id);
    });

    passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
      User.getUserById(id, function(err, user) {
        done(err, user);
      });
    });

      passport.use(new LocalStrategy(function(username,password,done){
        User.getUserByUsername(username,function(err,user){
          console.log("user object  is : "+user);

          if(err) throw err;
          if(!user){
            return done(null,false,{message:'Unknown user'});
          }
         //The problem lies in the second argument below calling function 
          User.comparePassword(password,user.passowrd,function(err,isMatch){
            console.log("Value of isMatch is :"+isMatch);
            console.log("user.password is : "+user.password);
            if(err) return done(err);
            if(isMatch){
              return done(null,user);
            }else{
              return done(null,false,{message : 'Invalid Password'});
            }
          });
        });
      }));
```

but the Problem is.,when i am calling **`comparePassword()`** method by sending **`password`** as first argument(which has been posted from login form) and **`user.passowrd`** as **second argument** which is already stored in mongoose., the function implementation in other file **`/models/user.js`** is not getting the second argument's value i.e., `user.passowrd`.

below is the code for **/models/user.js**

```
var mongoose= require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/nodeauth');
var db = mongoose.connection;
var bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');

//user Schema
var UserSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  username : {
    type :String,
    index: true
  },
  password:{
    type : String
  },
  email:{
    type : String
  },
  name:{
    type : String
  },
  profileimage:{
    type : String
  }
  });
var User= module.exports=mongoose.model('User',UserSchema);

module.exports.createUser=function(newUser,callback){
  bcrypt.genSalt(10,function(err,salt){
    bcrypt.hash(newUser.password,salt,function(err,hash){
      newUser.password=hash;
      newUser.save(callback);

    });
  });
}

module.exports.getUserById = function(id,callback){
  User.findById(id,callback);
}
module.exports.getUserByUsername = function(username,callback){
  console.log("indside getUserByUsername impl., username is :"+username);
  var query ={username:username};
  User.findOne(query,callback);
}
//here in the below calling function., the second passed argument 'hash' is  showing as 'undefined' in the result.

module.exports.comparePassword = function(candidatePassword,hash,callback){
  console.log("indside comparePassword impl., candidatePassword is :"+candidatePassword);
  console.log("hash of the password is  :"+hash);
  bcrypt.compare(candidatePassword, hash, function(err, isMatch) {

  callback(null,isMatch);
});
}
```

**Below is the output for console.log statements written for debugging purpose:**

[image]

What wrong i did in the code, i.e., i am getting **'undefined'** instead of stored password for comparison, which was sent as second argument to **`comparePassword`** method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check the spell of user.passowrd. You have to give like user.password